# How to return unique items in nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filtering

I have an object that contains a list of attributes with corresponding attribute values.

Some of the arrays of values have duplicates values that I'd like to remove.

**Example**

```
let attributes = [{
  "attribute": "Size",
  "values": ["S", " S", "M", "L", "L"]
},{
  "attribute": "Shape",
  "values": ["Square", "Round", "Square", " Square", " Square"]
}]

let filtered_attributes = attributes.forEach(el => {
  el.map(a => a.values.trim())
  .filter((item, pos, self) => { return self.indexOf(item) === pos })
  .sort();
})
```

**Desired Output**

```
[{
  "attribute": "Size",
  "values": ["L", "M", "S"]
},{
  "attribute": "Shape",
  "values": ["Round", "Square"]
}]
```

How can I return a list of unique values (those with whitespace first trimmed) for each object in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map` plus destructuring to get to the props, then you can `filter` your values prop from there, `trim`ming each value inside of the `filter`.

```js
let attributes = [{
  "attribute": "Size",
  "values": ["S", " S", "M", "L", "L"]
},{
  "attribute": "Shape",
  "values": ["Square", "Round", "Square", " Square", " Square"]
}]

// usage example:
let unique = attributes.map(({ attribute, values }) => ({
  attribute, values: values.filter((v, i, s) => s.indexOf(v.trim()) === i) // v, i, s = value, index, self
}));
console.log(unique)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Set and spread operator instead of filter:

```
let attributes = [{
 "attribute": "Size",
  "values": ["S", " S", "M", "L", "L"]
},{
  "attribute": "Shape",
  "values": ["Square", "Round", "Square", " Square", " Square"]
}]

attributes.forEach(el => {
  el.values = [...new Set(el.values.map(a => a.trim()))].sort();
})
console.log(attributes);
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why `filtered_attributes` is `undefined` and we're logging `attributes`.

Comment: forEach only iterates over elements - it doesn't return anything (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). But inside forEach we change the content for each attribute

Comment: If you want filtered_attributes to contain your change you should change it to the following: let filtered_attributes = attributes.map(el => {
  el.values = [...new Set(el.values.map(a => a.trim()))].sort();
  return el
})

Comment: Awesome. Thank you Alonas :)